# Python bar plot vs line plot: why are the x-axis labels different?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using a single dataframe merged from two source dataframes to plot a data series. Both plots work well, but I'm having trouble controlling the x-axis labels displayed in the line plot, even though the code I'm using for both plots is otherwise identical.
This code:

```
merged_data = pd.merge(newdata, newstuff, on='Date')
ax = merged_data.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(20, 7))
ax.set_xticklabels(merged_data.Date, rotation=45)
ax.set_ylabel('CPI vs. Wages and salaries - 12-month change')
ax.set_xlabel('Dates')
```

Produces this output:
[image: bar graph]

But this code:

```
ax = merged_data.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20, 7))
ax.set_xticklabels(merged_data.Date, rotation=45)
ax.set_ylabel('CPI vs. Wages and salaries - 12-month change')
ax.set_xlabel('Dates')
```

gives me this output:
[image: line graph]
I certainly don't mind having fewer labels so they'll be easier to read, but the labels I'm getting on the line graph don't correspond to the actual data: the data covers 20 years (as you can see from the labels in the first graph), but the line-graph labels only cover the first two years.

From carefully visually scanning the graphs themselves, they both seem to be tracking the full data set.
Any idea what I'm missing?
Thanks,

Comment: Bar plots are intended when your bars represent categories that are likely unordered (i.e. cat, dog, fox, bear). You need to label every bar because if you just label cat and fox how is anyone supposed to know the others are bear and dog? Line plots are meant for an x variable that is numeric and since the number line is well defined, there's no need to label all of the infinite points

Comment: As for the mess up, my guess is something weird is happening when you do `ax.set_xticklabels(merged_data.Date, rotation=45)` (Just remove it). The line plot should correctly set the labels, you may just be messing them up after it's done so.

Comment: Thanks. You were correct that removing the ax.set_xticklabels line got rid of the skewed labels. But that left me with labels between 0-70 in increments of 10. Is there a way to get the plot to work with my existing dates in some format?

Comment: Oh yes, that's becasue it will plot with respect to the Series index labels. My suggestion would be to turn those dates into a Period dtype and then set them to the index before you plot. That should work. Also it might just work to set the Date column to be the index since your form of dates `YYYYQq` will string sort the same way as it would sort when converted to a number.